# For which $x_0,y_0$ this equation has unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $$\begin{cases} y'=x^4 \ln y \\ y(x_0)=y_0 \end{cases}$$ For which $x_0,y_0$ this equation has unique solution?

I was trying to do it from Picard–Lindelöf theorem so firstly I wanted to check Lipschitz continuity. However I get: $$|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|=x^4|\ln \frac{y_1}{y_2}|\le L|y_1-y_2|$$ and I don't see how to continue it so I am not certain if it is a good point of view.

Can you have me any tips how to solve such a task?

**EDIT:**
Does nobody really want to help? I really want to understand this task, I do not want to find a solution, just learn how to approach such tasks in general, because I could not find similar ones in the forum. Everywhere I see tasks where $ x_0, y_0 $ are already given and you need to find a specificity range

Comment: $y=1$ is a solution

Answer (score 1):

Near $y=0$, $(\ln y)'=\frac1y$ is unbounded. Therefore the Lipschitz condition will not hold. In order to use the Picard–Lindelöf theorem, you have to consider to cases $0<a<y<b<1$ and $y>a>1$ for the Lipschitz condition.